# How to get root cause of AssertionFailure 'Table not found' when using MariaDB with Hibernate Filter?

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

I am using the following test setup for **evaluating Hibernate Filter features** with various databses:

- Spring Boot Starter 1.5.3.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.10.Final
- Spring Data Envers 1.1.3.RELEASE -> Spring Data JPA 1.11.3.RELEASE
- mariadb-java-client 1.5.9
- HikariCP 2.6.1
- MariaDB 10.1.22 (docker container)

The **database schema is setup using Flyway** and works fine, so the table is there.

Now I've got an **entity class 'User'** with a custom table name and a filter for the active-field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"users\"")
@FilterDef(name = "activeUsers", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "active", type = "boolean"))
@Filter(name = "activeUsers", condition = "\"active\" = :active")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private boolean active;

    // getters/setters (not shown)

}
```

In addition, a custom repository is provided to allow usage of the filter:

```
public interface RepositoryExtended<T> {
     Iterable<T> findAll(boolean active);
}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements RepositoryExtended<User> {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Iterable<User> findAll(boolean active) {

        EntityManagerHolder holder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(entityManagerFactory);
        EntityManager entityManager = holder.getEntityManager();
        Filter hibernateFilter = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).enableFilter("activeUsers").setParameter("active", active);
        hibernateFilter.validate();

        Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).disableFilter("activeUsers");
        return users;
    }
}
```

Final the **UserRepository based on Spring Data JPA CrudRepository and the custom repository** from above:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, RepositoryExtended<User> {
}
```

Now the **test setup**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { DBConfig.class })
public class UserRepositoryTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        user = new User();
        user.setActive(true);
        user = repository.save(user);

        user2 = new User();
        user2.setActive(true);
        user2 = repository.save(user2);

        em.flush();
       em.clear();
    }

@Test
    public void filteredQueries() {

        assertEquals(2, repository.count());
        assertTrue(repository.findAll().iterator().hasNext());

        Iterable<User> findAllActive = repository.findAll(true); // THIS FAILS
        assertTrue(findAllActive.iterator().hasNext());
    }
}
```

with the **JDBC and Hibernate/JPA settings**:

```
mariadb.db.driver=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
mariadb.db.url=jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/PRORK
mariadb.db.username=root
mariadb.db.password=root

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=PRORK
```

Used in bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfig {

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource(Environment env) {
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/PRORK");
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername("root");
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword("root");
    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}

@Bean
public Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.dialect, "org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect");
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto,"validate");
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.show_sql,"true");
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.format_sql,"true");
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers,"true");
    jpaProperties.put(hibernate.default_schema, "PRORK");
    return jpaProperties;
}

@Bean
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("test.prork");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return transactionManager;
}

}
```

**Running the test results in the following stacktrace:**

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table `PRORK`.`users` not found
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.DynamicFilterAliasGenerator.getAlias(DynamicFilterAliasGenerator.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.internal.FilterHelper.render(FilterHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.FilterHelper.render(FilterHelper.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.filterFragment(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3641)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.JoinSequence.toJoinFragment(JoinSequence.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.JoinSequence.toJoinFragment(JoinSequence.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.addJoinNodes(JoinProcessor.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor.processJoins(JoinProcessor.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:785)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:546)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3318)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:3611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:656)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:633)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at test.prork.persistence.UserRepositoryImpl.findAll(UserRepositoryImpl.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:479)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at test.prork.persistence.AbstractUserRepositoryTests.filteredQueries(AbstractUserRepositoryTests.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The **same test works without problems for H2, PostgreSQL and Oracle DB, only MariaDB fails**. Also note that the findAll() method without Hibernate filter works just fine, the count method as well. Some other basic CrudRepository method tests not shown work as well for all four database systems.

*Am I doing something wrong with my method applying the filter and for the other database systems it just works by accident?*

*Or are there any setup errors or special settings to keep in mind for MariaDB with Hibernate Filters?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two problems** in the setup/code:

First **MySQL / MariaDB don't have a schema**, so **remove** the

`hibernate.default_schema`

**setting** to *get rid of the AssertionFailure* as they use catalog and not schema. Should be given by the JDBC connection anyways. [This Hibernate JIRA ticket gave me the necessary hint](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10490), although there are more tickets pointing directly/indirectly to this cause.

Second for **MariaDB using the filter will still fail** (maybe for MySQL as well, did not test it). This is **because of the quotes in the Filter condition are in JPA style, but only the *[hibernate legacy quotes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-quoted-identifiers)* (i.e. using *backtips*) seem to work for now.** No quotes at all does not work either.

The entity now looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"users\"")
@FilterDef(name = "activeUsers", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "active", type = "boolean"))
@Filter(name = "activeUsers", condition = "`active` = :active")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private boolean active;
    // getters/setters (not shown)
}
```

> A **last tip** as it helped me identifying the second issue: **take a close
>   look at the Hibernate SQL queries generated** from HQL, especially regarding quotes etc.

---

**Update:** I've opened a [ticket in the Hibernate JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11717) as it may be a Hibernate (MariaDB dialect) issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, the @Filter condition value is an SQL expression that is passed directly to the database.

It seems Mariadb supports both type of quotes except when sql_mode = "ANSI_QUOTES" https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/quotes